# A question on the Epsilon-Delta definition

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

I'm starting to study calculus and I stumbled upon the Epsilon-Delta limit definition. It is apparently used as a foundation for the most basic theorems in calculus. So I was trying to use the definition to disprove (by contradiction) that the limit of $f(x) = \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ as $x$ approaches $2$ is $5$.

I first used the definition to reach the statements:

$0 \lt \vert x−2 \vert \lt \delta$

$\vert x-3 \vert \lt \varepsilon$   (Already factored and subtracted)

Now I have no idea what to do. If I gave the correct answer, $4$, then it would follow that $\vert x-2 \vert \lt \varepsilon$ and so I could've just defined delta to be equal to epsilon and it would suffice... what am I missing?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: So for $\epsilon < 1$ there is no choice of $\delta$ for which the limit definition is satisfied, therefore $ \lim _{x\to 2} f(x)=5$ is false

Comment: $\vert x-3 \vert$ is not at all like $\vert f(x) - 5 \vert.$ That's one thing holding you back.

Comment: Ok, @Shaun, thanks.

Comment: @WW1 I must be be completely misunderstanding this, but what if: ε=0.5? Then solving the inequation  |x-3|<0.5 we have 2.5<x<3.5. And going back to the inequation 0<|x−2|<δ we have a real range for delta: if delta is bigger than 1.5 this inequation is necessarily true.

Comment: $2.5<x<3.5$. has to be true for EVERY... $$x\in (2-\delta, 2+\delta)$$ (except possibly at $x=2$), but it is not true for $x=2.1$

Answer (score 3):

For an epsilon-delta limit statement to be true, you need to prove $\forall \varepsilon \gt 0 \exists \delta$ such that a particular statement is true.  That means to prove the statement is false, you must prove $\exists \varepsilon \gt 0 \forall \delta$ the same statement is false.

In this case, the statement is that whenever $0 \lt \vert x-2 \vert \lt \delta$ we have that $\vert f(x)-5 \vert \lt \varepsilon$.  So choose a specific $\varepsilon$; say, $\varepsilon = 0.5$.  You can see pretty easily that there is no $\delta$ that forces $\vert f(x)-5 \vert \lt \frac 12$ whenever $0 \lt \vert x-2 \vert \lt \delta$ because whenever $\vert x-2 \vert \lt \min (\delta, \frac 14)$, the inequality $\vert f(x)-5 \vert \lt \frac 12$ is false.

Comment: "...the inequality $\vert f(x)-5 \vert \lt \frac 12$ is false" : absent factoring out the $(x-2)$ from the numerator and denominator, how do you know this?

Comment: @user2661923 There's nothing wrong with factoring out $x-2$.  The point is that the question seems to be focused on the region $0 \lt \vert x-3 \vert \lt \varepsilon$ and that's the wrong region to focus on.

Comment: This does not answer my question.  Your answer did not discuss factoring out $~(x-2).~$  Therefore, in any neighborhood around $~x=2,~$ you will have a fraction approaching $~\dfrac{0}{0}.~$  So, on that basis, how do you know that the inequality $~|f(x) - 5| < (1/2)~$ is false?

Comment: I don't need it for the whole neighborhood.  I just need it for a single number within the interval.  Do the calculation for 2.00001.  And what I said is that you can see it pretty easily.  One way to see it easily is, as you note, to factor out $x-2$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what min(x,y)  and "force" mean in this context. I'm very confused... maybe I should just do Calculus without rigour and then eventually get these definitions straight, maybe after I study symbollic logic, set theory and such. But thank you for the attempt.

Comment: Also thank you for editing my answer.

Comment: @Davi Here's the point.  Choose some $\delta$.  It's just a number.  Typically it's a small number but it doesn't have to be.  We're just talking about the smaller number between whatever $\delta$ you happen to choose and $\frac 14$.  That's what we mean by $\min$.  I'm using "force" colloquially.  There's no way to choose $\delta$ so that **all** of the numbers $x$ that satisfy $0 \lt \vert x-2 \vert \lt \delta$ also satisfy $\vert f(x)-5 \vert \lt \frac 12$.  That's because we can always find **some** number that's very close to $x=2$ that doesn't satisfy the necessary inequality.

Answer (score 0):

To get a feel for this, you can graph the function $f(x)$ and (tentatively) define $f(2) = 5$. After this you can inspect the graph and then (with great confidence) set $\varepsilon = 1$. Now for any $\delta \gt 0$ select the the smallest positive integer $n$ such that

$$ \frac{1}{n} \lt \delta$$

Then set $x_0 = 2 - \frac{1}{n}$ and observe that

$$0 \lt \vert x_0−2 \vert \lt \delta \quad \land \quad \vert f(x_0)-5 \vert = \vert 4 - \frac{1}{n}-5 \vert = 1 + \frac 1n$$